# Once NSTimer stop dismiss my view controller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am using `NSTimer`,

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

then my 60 second count down timer program

```
-(void) updateCountdown {
    int hours, minutes, seconds;

   secondsLeft++;
    hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
    minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;


    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",  seconds];

}
```

my question is after 60 second dismiss my count down view controller page .. anyone can help me

Comment: replace `repeats: YES];` with `repeats: NO];` in your initialization of `NSTimer`.

Comment: You want to dismiss you controller after 60 seconds  or not please clear question

Comment: yes i want dismiss my view controller after 60 sec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if `repeats: YES];` check like your `seconds` reaches or greater than `60`, invalidate your timer and dismiss your VC

```
if (seconds >60)
{
[timer invalidate];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

else call your timer once using `repeats: NO];`

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];
```

and call the function like

```
-(void) updateCountdown {
   [timer invalidate];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I am not able to access timer in my method which is called so how to invalidate that??@Anbu.Karthick

Answer (score 2):

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown:) userInfo:nil repeats: NO]; // set No

-(void) updateCountdown:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [timer invalidate];
   // dismiss your controller
}
```